# Reorder table rows using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drag-and-drop

I am using sort table rows with jQuery using drag and drop method for table sort. Now the issue I am facing is after saving order to DB how can I set the table on refresh page or load?

Means my table is in HTML and I can get order from db in PHP but how can reorder with that sort?
My table structure is like :

```
`order`->fields ('id'=> int,'order'=>int,'code'=>int)
```

While in above MySQL table order is used for table row reordering and code for unique table. I am confused and don’t know how to sort out this issue.

Comment: You can dynamically create the table structure with the DB value and will design the DB accordingly. If the order will come as id, order and then code, table header should have the same value. And if it change, the header should also change. The same thing for getting the value for those fields. You have to make the query with the same order using ORDER BY.

Comment: @Prava-MindfireSolutions My table already created .Only `tr` id have dynamic values that are i use for ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Edit3: I deleted a bunch of the stuff i just had, so if you want to see it agian just let me know and i'll send it to you, but this should answer your question:

**i see that you said your HTML is already set. Thats an easy fix. Load your html via php like so:**

```
<?
   $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY order');
   $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    echo '<div id = "tablediv"><table>
                      <tr>
                        <th>My Table Header</th>
                      </tr>'; 

               while($row = $STH->fetch()) 
                {                     
                    echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td>My DB Data Via String Concat</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                }
                echo'</table>';
                echo'</div>';

?>
```

Basically just loop through your mysql result and create table rows based on how many there are with a simple php while loop.

edit 4: added PDO security as suggested by tadman

Comment: But the problem is my html is already set ,table already created only id if `tr` are dynamic .So if i got order how can i reorder according to new order ? got my point

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Added another edit. Instead of making your pages in raw html, create the html within PHP echos so you can loop through the number of rows in your database.

Comment: If you're posting queries with the awfully out of date `mysql_query` interface that are littered with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because of a reckless disregard for [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you're promoting dangerously bad habits. Code this terrible **will** get you burned in the worst possible way eventually.

Comment: @tadman yes i know that was an example of literally the first web page i ever mad. I edit my code to more specifically fix his problem with no security issues. If you agree could you remove your downvote? :P

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get you .If one row have `order` 2 while first that one was on `3` order how i will set that to position `2` ? means how i will contact that html to that row

Comment: It would take a few minutes to update this to use PDO and demonstrate how to do it properly. That would make it a great answer.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ If you change your rows on this list. Jquery UI knows the order. So if you perform an ajax call to update your database, it can just reset every single row's "order" attribute every single time. (Instead of updating just the rows you want to move, it updates every single row even if they stay the same)

Comment: @tadman I've never heard of PDO, would that be considered a standard these days? I deleted my code so i dont know if you remember specifics, but i dont understand how it would susceptible to SQL Injections when there is no input from the client side whatsoever.

Comment: You had `$_POST` data in there, so it was wide open. 
[PDO is pretty easy to pick up](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and using placeholders in a disciplined fashion makes it almost impossible to screw that sort of thing up.

Comment: @tadman The only place i used $_POST data was in my Ajax page. It used was used to reference an array created by my jqueryui sortable table. It had nothing to do with actual SQL statements.

I understand the necessity of prepared statements, but how would that be beneficial in something like this?

Comment: The way I read it, it ended up in the query. In any case, `mysql_query` is on the chopping block so to post answers with it is a waste of time.

Comment: @tadman I just edited my answer. Is that a little closer to what you're talking about? (Sorry for a million responses btw i'm still learning and want to make sure i'm doing things correctly)